# Breslov Lecha Dodi in Katamon, Jerusalem

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation, synagogue, song-poetry, kabbalat-shabbat

I've been twice to the Breslov Minyan next to the hospital in Katamon for Kabbalat Shabbat. It's probably my favourite minyan in the world, and the most amazing part of the davening is the Lecha Dodi, which goes through six or seven melodies and lasts about 25 minutes. Looking online I can't find any information on the minyan or the melodies they sing for Lecha Dodi - can anybody recall/ does anybody have a recording?

Comment: Sounds impressive. Do they use a different tune for each verse?

Comment: Maybe you can ask the folks at the minyan?

Comment: Is it always the same tunes each time? I don't know what information you are looking for otherwise?

Comment: @Daniel I don't know what version of the poem they have, but every version I've seen has more than seven verses. Note that the question says the song "goes through six or seven melodies".

Comment: @msh210 Yeah, but that could have been an estimation.

Comment: Yes, a couple of tunes are used for two consecutive verses but it's never more than that. Unfortunately I'm not at the minyan frequently so I can't ask them.